# How to write a generic usort filter function

Tags: php

I wish to create a usort function. The function uses the value of an object field to compare against each other. However, I wish to set the object field via a variable, but I'm not able to. The following is a slimmed down piece of the code:

```
<?php
    function projSort($a, $b){
        return $a->{$sort} > $b->{$sort};
    }
    usort($projects, 'projSort');
?>
```

`$sort` is set via `$_POST` and contains a string. When I use the above code I get a `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property`. What am I missing?

Comment: `$sort` does not exist inside the `function`'s scope. [PHP: Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Use a closure, because it's easy to pass in additional arguments via `use`: `usort($projects, function ($a, $b) use ($sort){
        return $a->{$sort} > $b->{$sort};
    });`

Comment: @MarkBaker: You're right. I've been looking at this the wrong way. I was hoping to keep the function separate from the usort. Is that possible, should I still want that?

Comment: Well you could create a `myUsort()` function that used the closure approach, but you call it using `myUsort($projects, $sort)`; or you could create a class-based function with $sort as a property set independently, and pass that class/method in the call to usort()

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `global` or am I missing something big?

```
function projSort($a, $b){
    global $sort;
    return $a->{$sort} > $b->{$sort};
}
```

If you want to avoid globals, you can use `$_POST` directly:

```
function projSort($a, $b){
    $sort = sanitized($_POST['sort']);
    return $a->{$sort} > $b->{$sort};
}
```

Comment: That fact that using globals is generally a very bad principle